# adding a delay before item reverts - draggable jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to add a delay between when the user drags and drops the div, and when the div reverts back.

so upon mouse up, to when the revert action begins I would like to have a short delay.

Here the jQuery:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({  revert: true , revertDuration: 1000 });
```

and here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YxBP9/54/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can custom revert function then return true to revert that item in **[revert](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert)** option

```
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable({  revert: function(){$(this).delay(1000);return true;} , revertDuration: 1000 });
```

Hope this help,

Here some fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/YxBP9/73/

Comment: Do you have any ideas of a workaround technique to keep the letters interactive (moveable), while there is a delay on the revert function?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do but if the letter is movable, where is the position of letter to revert, first or last.

Comment: so the delay works well, except once the letter is initially moved, the revert delay begins counting, and you are unable to move the letter again until the delay is finished, and the letter has been reverted back. Is there a workaround to keep the letter interactive, even once the letter has been moved?